# VBA stops running when value is written in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am organizing a dirty text in an organised table. And this code stops when the cell the marked line is completed. Can you help me to make it continuing the loop?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sh7 As Worksheet

    Dim CNAME As String

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet6")
    Set sh7 = Worksheets("Sheet7")    
    lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For n = 1 To lr
        If InStr(1, sh.Cells(n, 1), "CALL:") = 1 Then
            CNAME = sh.Cells(n, 7).Value    
            Ci = sh.Cells(n + 1, 7).Value    
            Cpd = sh.Cells(n + 1, 7).Value    
        Else
            If InStr(1, sh.Cells(n, 1), "Topic:") = 1 Then
                T = sh.Cells(n, 2)
                Tpd = sh.Cells(n + 1, 2)
                Types = sh.Cells(n + 4, 2)
                DM = sh.Cells(n + 5, 2)
                D = sh.Cells(n + 5, 4)
                OD = sh.Cells(n + 6, 2)
                lr7 = sh7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 1).Value = CNAME '********This is the last line it runs.
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 2).Value = Ci
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 3).Value = Cpd
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 4).Value = T
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 5).Value = Tpd
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 6).Value = Types
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 7).Value = DM
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 8).Value = D
                sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 9).Value = OD
            End If  
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: define your `lr7` Variable. Also add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to prevent typo or variables undeclared.

Comment: Variables Ci, Cpd, and CNAME don’t appear to be getting a value in the else part of the condition yet they are trying to put their value into a cell. This is probably why it is stopping at CNAME.

Comment: If you set CNAME to empty string at the beginning it will probably push past this line but it will stop on the next line because you have the same problem. On second look, those are Variants so they can be null. Set CNAME to what it should be or set it to empty string at the beginning of the sub and you should be good.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Access? I think what you are trying to do is better suited for a database. The solution will be much cleaner and knowing how to write queries is a big deal these days. Excel and Access play together nicely and you can write custom database functions in VBA.

Comment: What do you mean "this code stops".  Does it just stop?  Does it give an error?  (If so, what error?  Is it highlighting the line `sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 2).Value = Ci` when you go into debug, or is it highlighting the `sh7.Cells(lr7 + 1, 1).Value = CNAME` line?)  Does Excel crash and you have to restart?

Answer (score 1):

You should get in the habit of defining all variables and supplying a default value.

EDIT:
It seems my original conclusion was incorrect. Upon further inspection I see what might be an issue in your code. Both times where you are trying to get the last row, you are using Rows.Count as a parameter.

Maybe change these

```
lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr7 = sh7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

To this (note that I use the sheet variable in the first param)

```
lr = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr7 = sh7.Cells(sh7.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Although it is a (very) good idea to always qualify things like `Rows.Count` with the appropriate sheet, that shouldn't be an issue here because both `sh` and `sh7` are defined as being in the `ActiveWorkbook`, so their `Rows.Count` will have the same value as the default `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`.

Comment: Yes, however, I'm not convinced either are referring to the active workbook. I'm almost certain lr7 is not. I also think you should never have to guess when reading code. If it's ActiveSheet they want then say `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` so that it is clear.

Comment: `sh7` is set using `Set sh7 = Worksheets("Sheet7")` which is equivalent to `Set sh7 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")`.  `lr7` is assigned a value using `lr7 = sh7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` which is equivalent to `lr7 = sh7.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.  The `ActiveSheet` will be in the `ActiveWorkbook` and therefore will have the same `Rows.Count` as `sh7` does, so it should be fine.  (Still a good idea to qualify it but, unless the user has been manually changing workbooks while the code is running, it won't be an issue in this situation.)

Comment: So you're saying that `sh7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` gives you the last row even if `sf7` is not the active sheet? It looks as though it would pass the row count of active sheet which would produce an unintended result.

Comment: The problem is that `sh7` is probably not the active worksheet. It should always be qualified.

Comment: `Rows.Count` is either 1048576 in new-format Excel workbooks, and it is 65536 in older ones.  So `sh7.Rows.Count` and `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` will both return the same number. (And it gives an error if you are on a `Chart`, but the error isn't happening at the point where that is used, so that doesn't seem to be an issue.)  So, as long as the user is not mixing workbook types, an unqualified `Rows.Count` shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What happens when you add one to the very last Excel row...`lr7 + 1` and try to use that value to reference a cell? I know this isn't the issue, but it's a thought on this. I still think there is an issue with which sheet is active. @YowE3K any ideas on what might be the real issue then. It's hard to tell with more code and context.

Comment: Yeah, `lr7 + 1` would certainly give an error if `lr7` was equal to `Rows.Count`, but I can't see how that can occur with an `End(xlUp)` being used.  It might accidentally set `lr7` to 1 if every row was in use, but I can't think how the "cursor" could be left at the last row.  I think we need to see whether the OP is getting an error message.  That might help narrow down the problem.  (They might just mean it only ever updates one cell - in which case it could be a simple data issue.)